# How to Serve Mac Applications?

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop

Can you put a mac application on a home file server, open the app from the client machine in finder, and use it just like it was on the client machine?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes, you just drag-copy the app to the server, and then anyone can double-click it and launch it from there. This is true of any app that comes on a disk image that you just mount and drag-copy into your Applications folder.

However, some bigger apps have a bunch of libraries/frameworks and templates and fonts and things that they like to install in other parts of the system. So those apps are a little harder to host from a server. These are the apps that come as an installer package .pkg file, or as a custom installer app. Especially ones whose installer requires admin permission to run.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good, how about Adobe Photoshop Elements? Do you think it would be able to if I deactivate the license on the computer it resides on now and went to the adobe website to download it for my server computer?

Comment: @Hunter Licensing schemes like that usually lock the app to the machine it's running on, not the machine whose disk it's hosted on. So I wouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: Ok, I was just wanting to make sure since I use the program as well as another person in the house, so I didn't really see a moral problem with it since it wouldn't be available to just anyone on the internet who wanted it. Thank you for the advice though! I can't stand Adobe anyway right now and probably need to look for a new tool!